# (Solution Verification) How should I move forward with these compound propositions?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

The question is the following :

Let $P(x)$, $Q(x)$, $R(x)$ and $S(x)$ be the statements "x is a duck", "x is one of my poultries", "x is an officer", "x is willing to waltz". Now consider the following 4 statements,

1. No ducks are willing to waltz.
2. No officers ever decline to waltz.
3. All my poultries are ducks.
4. My poultries are not officers.

Does (4) follow (1), (2), and (3)? If not, is here a correct conclusion?

---

Now if I attempt to solve this with reasoning,
1 and 2 imply ducks are not officers (a). 1 and 3 are kind of tricky, "All my poultries are ducks" doesn't mean "all ducks are poultries", which means these two imply "At least one of my ducks is poultry" (b). Now from (a) and (b), we can conclude "at least one of my ducks are not officers".

So to answer the initial question, No, 4 doesn't follow 1, 2, and 3. And the correct conclusion is "at least one of my ducks are not officers". Is this the correct solution?

Now if I try to do the same mathematically with quantifiers and connectives,
The four statements can be represented as the following :

1. $\forall x \bigl(\lnot P(x) \land S(x) \bigr)$
2. $\forall x \bigl( R(x) \land S(x) \bigr)$
3. $\forall x \bigl( Q(x) \to P(x) \bigr)$
4. $\forall x \bigl( Q(x) \land \lnot R(x) \bigr)$

> The domain is all ducks, poultries and officers.

This is where I'm stuck. How can I move forward with this now? Considering (If) the solution via reasoning was correct, using quantifiers and connectives, the answer should be $$\exists x\bigl( P(x) \to R(x) \bigr)$$I might just be totally wrong in every sense here, I'll appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Comment: 1) must be $\forall x (Px \to \lnot Sx)$ or equivalently : $\lnot \exists x (Px \land Sx)$

Comment: 2) is (deliberately ?) ambiguous. It can ve "Every officer is willing to waltz". If so, it must be $\forall x (Rx \to Sx)$.

Comment: 4) is wrong. It must be $\forall x (Qx \to \lnot Rx)$

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you have : 1) $∀x(Px → ¬Sx)$, 2) $∀x(Rx → Sx)$, i.e. equivalently: $∀x(¬Sx → ¬Rx)$, and 3) $∀x(Q(x) → P(x))$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Could you please elaborate on how you got $\forall x(\lnot Sx \to \lnot Rx)$ from 1 and 2? I can see $\forall x( Rx \to \lnot Px)$ happening (resolution).

Comment: Elaborate what ? If you agree with the proposed symbolization of 2) the equivalent expression is obtained by Contraposition: $A \to B \equiv \lnot B \to \lnot A$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh I'm sorry, I misread that. I thought you got that from 1 **AND** 2.

Comment: No problem: now it is quite easy to "link together" 1,2 and 3 to derive 4.